# how to convert a CNPhoneNumber to string in swift4?

Tags: swift, casting, contacts

I am using this code for getting contact number from contacts app but when I want to show the number in label I get this warning and doesn't work:
Cast from 'CNPhoneNumber' to unrelated type 'String' always fails

```
func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contacts: [CNContact]) {
    contacts.forEach {(contact) in
        for number in contact.phoneNumbers{
            let phone = number.value
            print(phone)
            numberLabel.text = phone as! String
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TRY :**

```
if let phone = number.value as? CNPhoneNumber {
    print(phone.stringValue)
} else {
   print("number.value not of type CNPhoneNumber")
}
```

also take a look at [CNContact](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cncontact?language=swift) , [CNPhoneNumber](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cnphonenumber?language=swift)

Comment: that is true but it show in label :<CNPhoneNumber: 0x600000222dc0: stringValue=888-555-1212, initialCountryCode=(null)>
where is the problem?

Comment: how can I get contact name?
in contact name it is character how can I cast it to string?

Answer (score 2):

You can get PhoneNumber value as `CNLabeledValue`.

```
for number in contact.phoneNumbers{
    if let number = phoneNumber.value as? CNPhoneNumber, let phoneLabel = phoneNumber.label {
      let phoneLocalizedLabel = CNLabeledValue.localizedStringForLabel(phoneLabel)
          numberLabel.text = "\(phoneLocalizedLabel) : \(number.stringValue)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func getContact(){
    let numeroinc = self.numero.text!
    let contactStore = CNContactStore()
    var numeroScodeCuntry = ""
    let keys = [
        CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName),
        CNContactPhoneNumbersKey,
        CNContactEmailAddressesKey
        ] as [Any]
    let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keys as! [CNKeyDescriptor])
    for char in UserDefaults.standard.string( forKey: "cc" )!.count ... numeroinc.count-1 {
        let index = numeroinc.index(numeroinc.startIndex, offsetBy: char)
        numeroScodeCuntry.append(numeroinc[index])
    }
    numeroScodeCuntry = formattedNumber2(number:numeroScodeCuntry)
    print("numeroScodeCuntry", numeroScodeCuntry)
    do {
        try contactStore.enumerateContacts(with: request){
            (contact, stop) in
            // Array containing all unified contacts from everywhere
            self.contacts.append(contact)
            for phoneNumber in contact.phoneNumbers {
                
                if let number = phoneNumber.value as? CNPhoneNumber, let label = phoneNumber.label {
                    let localizedLabel = CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber>.localizedString(forLabel: label)
                    print("\(contact.givenName) \(contact.familyName) tel:\(localizedLabel) -- \(number.stringValue), email: \(contact.emailAddresses)")
                    print("numeroScodeCuntry",numeroScodeCuntry ,"number.stringValue" , number.stringValue)
                    let numberContact = self.formattedNumber2(number:number.stringValue)
                    if (numeroScodeCuntry.isEqualToString(find: numberContact)){
                        self.numero.text = contact.givenName
                        print("contact.givenName",contact.givenName)
                        self.isNumber = false
                        break
                    }else{
                         self.isNumber = true
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
        }
        print(self.contacts)
    } catch {
        print("unable to fetch contacts")
    }
}
```

}

Comment: While this might answer the question, providing details as to how to reached the conclusion and your thought process will surely help the fellow asker. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)