# I need to extract data from contacts JSON response

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, contacts

I am trying to fetch data from contacts and I need to pass it into tableview, I have taken firstName, LastName and phoneNumber. I am getting an array for phone number I don't know how to take particular phone number from the response. please help me.

I have pasted the response for your reference.

```
[<CNContact: 0x155e8c1b0: identifier=DD78D98D-3ECD-4743-8FBB-AF67CC544BB7, givenName=S, familyName=Jerry Mom, organizationName=(null), phoneNumbers=(
"<CNLabeledValue: 0x280c8b200: identifier=10BB271D-611B-4D15-A452-BC553B79A9BF, label=_$!<Mobile>!$_, value=<CNPhoneNumber: 0x2816469c0: stringValue=+917904619229, initialCountryCode=(null)>>"
```

)
response for one array of contacts and it goes on .. 
I need to take this number alone 917904619229 from the array and I need to parse it into label.

I have loaded the table parsing for u r reference.

```
 let contactsList = contacts[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2") as? contactListCell
        cell?.profileName.text = contactsList.familyName
        cell?.profileCountry.text = "\(contactsList.phoneNumbers)"
        return cell!
 }
```

by using this `"\(contactsList.phoneNumbers)"` it was loading the entire array into the label.

```
[<CNContact: 0x155e8c1b0: identifier=DD78D98D-3ECD-4743-8FBB-AF67CC544BB7, givenName=S, familyName=Jerry Mom, organizationName=(null), phoneNumbers=(
"<CNLabeledValue: 0x280c8b200: identifier=10BB271D-611B-4D15-A452-BC553B79A9BF, label=_$!<Mobile>!$_, value=<CNPhoneNumber: 0x2816469c0: stringValue=+91790989898984619229, initialCountryCode=(null)>>"
```

), emailAddresses=(
), postalAddresses=(not fetched)>, !$_, value=>"
), emailAddresses=(
), postalAddresses=(not fetched)>, >"
), emailAddresses=(
), postalAddresses=(not fetched)>, >"
), emailAddresses=(
), postalAddresses=(not fetched)>, >"
)

Comment: You have to parse that stringValue from PhoneNumber array, can you please post real json so I can tell you how to parse?

Comment: I have pasted the real JSON response above

Comment: phoneNumbers=(
    "<CNLabeledValue: 0x280c8b200: identifier=10BB271D-611B-4D15-A452-BC553B79A9BF, label=_$!<Mobile>!$_, value=<CNPhoneNumber: 0x2816469c0: stringValue=+9175555904619229, initialCountryCode=(null)>>"
)

Comment: need to take string value from the phoneNumber Array

Comment: {
"familyName": "Jerry Mom",
"organizationName": "nil",
"phoneNumbers": [{
"stringValue:": "+917904619229 ",
"initialCountryCode": "IN "
}]
}
Is this correct, So i can tell you how to do it?

Comment: CNContact is not json is it, that's a class from Apple's Contacts framework?

Comment: yes correct please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert a CNPhoneNumber to string in swift4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50621917/how-to-convert-a-cnphonenumber-to-string-in-swift4)

Comment: @KarthickThavasimuthu... which value you want from `phoneNumber` Array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one for what you posted as json like this!!

```
{
    familyName = "Jerry Mom";
    organizationName = nil;
    phoneNumbers =     (
                {
            initialCountryCode = "IN ";
            "stringValue" = "+917904619229 ";
        }
    );
}

for phoneNumber in phoneNumbers {
 if let phoneValue = phoneNumber.object(forKey: "stringValue") as? String {
        print(phoneValue)
   }
}
```

Or

```
for phone in contact.phoneNumbers {
 if let phonValue = phone.value as? CNPhoneNumber {
    print(phonValue.stringValue)
  }
}
```